# arrowed breadcrumbs on hover

Tags: html, css, breadcrumbs

So im making a customized breadcrumbs for my new project, and when the user hovers over the link, its supposed to fill up the arrow within that link. Problem is, how can I do it. I tried different tricks/hacks, but theyre not working out. I tried using the invisible border, or background position, but theyre always out of position.

The way it works is when the user hovers over the link, it uses 2 images for the left breadcrumb arrow and the right. I just need them to be positioned correctly.

HTML

```
<div id="bcbox">
<!-- start: nav -->
<ul id="breadcrumb"><li><a href="http://******.com/index.php" title="Home">Home</a></li>
<!-- start: nav_bit -->
<li><a href="http://*******.com/index.php">****** forums</a></li>
<!-- end: nav_bit --><!-- start: nav_bit -->
<li><a href="Forum-Headquarters">Headquarters</a></li>
<!-- end: nav_bit --><!-- start: nav_bit_active -->
<li style="padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;">Announcements &amp; Important Information</li>
<!-- end: nav_bit_active --></ul>
<!-- end: nav -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
#bcbox {
background:#292929;height:38px;line-height:38px;color:#acacac;width:100%;overflow:hidden;margin:0;padding:0;border-top: 1px solid #464646;border-bottom: 1px solid #464646;
}
#breadcrumb{
height:38px;line-height:38px;color:#acacac;width:1150px;overflow:hidden;margin:0 auto;padding:0;border-left: 1px solid #464646;
}

#breadcrumb li{
list-style-type:none;float:left
}

#breadcrumb a{
background: url(http://******.com/images/Orbit/bcline.png) no-repeat right;height:38px;display:block;text-decoration:none;color:#fff;padding-left:10px;padding-right:19px
}
#breadcrumb a:hover {
background-color: #505050;
background-image: url(http://******.com/images/Orbit/bcline-hover-left.png), url(http://*****.com/images/Orbit/bcline-hover-right.png);
background-position: -111px, 111px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve requires lots of `::before` and `:after` and other pseudoclasses, it's better to have snippets for the cases like that because it's quite time-involving.

Here's a **[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/PqHuT/)** of a Bootstrap arrowed breadcrumbs.

Just inspect the elements and either make the same styles/markup in your example, or change the mine one so it fits your styles.

Comment: ...or a different version of the same thing - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/b16eb69676be73626013d1308fec4749

Comment: I tried to implement it on my board, I can't seem to figure out the problem with the arrows. I have a bar where the navigation goes, but it seems like its not working really well.   http://jsfiddle.net/2urhq/